# How to have javascript modify css link based on page name?

Tags: javascript

I want the below javascript to update the specific css link bootstrap.min.js if the page is named mypage.html.
How would I do that?

```
<html>
  <head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/bootstrap377.min.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/some_other_stylesheet.css"/>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var filename = location.href.split("/").slice(-1); 

    if (filename == "mypage.html") {
      HOW DO I DO THIS:  update the above stylesheet link to be bootstrap400.min.css (or should this script be before the css link?)
    }
  </script>


  </head>
  <body>
    this is a test
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't access the filename from the HTML

Comment: My example already accesses the filename, I need the script to modify the css link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `document.querySelector` to get a reference to the `link` element, then change the `href` property the usual way.

```
var filename = location.href.split("/").slice(-1); 

if (filename == "mypage.html") {
  var link = document.querySelector("link[href='/css/bootstrap377.min.css']");
  link.href = "/css/bootstrap400.min.css";
}
```

Comment: Excellent!  However I should have mentioned that my real world application has multiple css links so the only link to be updated is the link that contains "bootstrap.min.css".   How would I do that?

Comment: @user3302169 I updated my solution. You may want to edit your question with the information that there are multiple links.